# Error in Heroku run python manage.py syncdb

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm using django==1.5.1 and I got this error below. Earlier I was using django==1.4.2 and didn't got such error following the same tut in GSWD (I did not update the django version in the middle of the project).

```
(edu-venv)vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/projects/kodeworms$ heroku run python manage.py syncdb
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.9132
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the     ENGINE value. Check setti
ngs documentation for more details.
```

This looks like I missed something which is related more specifically to django==1.5.1 version. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone gave this solution and it worked for me

Original Link: http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/questions/1/error-in-heroku-run-python-managepy-syncdb/

If you type heroku config you'll get the heroku environment values.

Mine only showed:

HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL: postgres://tcmgahtgsrmufa:iyA2dKD5bnO4f7jyv6MSu4453g@ec2-54-225-68-241.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d6oj663f28smnh - there was no DATABASE_URL which dj_database_url.config needs. So then I found our from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql that you need to promote this to DATABASE_URL. The commands is : heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL (replace with whatever environment variable your set-up is using). So far so good. I came here to post as soon as I tried this out. I haven't rerun yet but it should work.